# Why is changing hyphenated crate names to underscored names possible and what are the rules for naming under such ambiguous scenarios?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I created a new Cargo project: `cargo new --lib hyphen-crate`.

**src/lib.rs**

```
pub fn add(a: u32, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a + b
}
```

**tests/addition.rs**

```
use hyphen_crate::add;

#[test]
fn addition_test() {
    assert_eq!(5, add(2, 3));
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "hyphen-crate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["xolve"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
```

I have searched and seen many discussions if hyphens should be allowed in names of crates or packages, but no link mentions a solution.

What I see is that the crate name `hyphen-crate` is automatically transformed to `hyphen_crate` and it compiles and tests successfully.

Comment: Why is what possible? Hyphens are allowed in package names, but they are converted to underscores internally, because hyphens are not valid characters in [Rust identifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html).

Comment: @Herohtar Put that in an answer and link to a source and you got yourself an upvote. It seems to me this is the only information the OP is really asking for.

Comment: help every beginner in Rust and don't use hyphens in crate name :p

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hyphens are allowed in package names, but they are converted to underscores internally, because hyphens are not valid characters in [Rust identifiers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html).

It seems that this automatic conversion was not always the case, and crates with hyphens had to be manually renamed in order to import them; eg. `extern crate "hyphen-crate" as hyphen_crate;`. See the [Hyphens Considered Harmful RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0940-hyphens-considered-harmful.md) for some details on that.

Comment: I know that identifiers cannot contain hyphens. The rules are very clear here: [https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html].
RFC940 which is linked in question and other page in language reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/extern-crates.html does mention this rule.
Thanks!